# Change of route name - Cloud foundry

Tags: rest, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

Each component(java) of a particular application is deployed on Cloud foundry as an application instance.

Each application instance(component) has its respective route name.

### [image]

Every component talks another component through REST.

Every component( say `component2`) has route name something like `component2-dev.abc.xyz.com`.

On [blue green deployment](https://github.com/bluemixgaragelondon/cf-blue-green-deploy) of any component(say `component2`) in PCFoundry the route name of a `component2` gets changed for some duration. Amidst this duration the `component1` cannot communicate, because `component1` is not aware of route name change. `component1` tries to communicate with old route name of `component2`

On restart of `component1`, `component1` can communicate with `component2`, which breaks the purpose of blue-green deployment

---

How to address the problem of route name change, during blue green deployment in PCF? How `component1`(on the fly) can refresh its cache with the new route name of `component2`?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you're doing blue/green wrong? or there's some other error happening. If done properly there should be zero downtime & your routes shouldn't change. If App A talks to App B using App B's route, say app-b.example.com, when you blue/green, you're pushing a new App B with a different route, like app-b-new.example.com. Then when the new App B is up and working, you're switching the route which happens instantaneously. Thus app-b.example.com goes from the original AppB to the new AppB. App A should never have it's route change, it's always accessing app-b.example.com.

Comment: @DanielMikusa New users should access `app-b-new.example.com` until you make route switching work fine with new App B having route  `app-b`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your latest comment. All I can do is reiterate that all your apps should always use app-b.example.com as the route. If you do that, there will be a seamless switch. The only thing you would use app-b-new.example.com to do is test and validate that your new app is up and working properly before switching traffic over to it. That could be done through a pipeline/automated tests or manually.

Comment: You need to use "service discovery" patterns, see e.g. https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/1-5/common/service-registry/index.html